¿Que hacer con una respuesta incorrecta?
Ho vi esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/66294/301324, la cual es la respuesta aceptada y con mayor cantidad de votos y corresponde a una pregunta bastante visitada.
Quizás yo no he entendido del todo su respuesta, pero considero que es incorrecta porque:

Parte diciendo que "Un Array vacio es igual a false", cuando en javascript un array vacío es true
No considera los operandos + de la pregunta, es decir ni siquiera está contestando el mismo ejercicio.

Normalmente votar negativo es la respuesta para estos casos, pero que hacer con una pregunta que tiene +60??
Si la idea es construir una base de conocimiento ¿No sería bueno borrar las respuestas flagrantemente incorrectas?

Me parece que este error es dañino, porque si bien la pregunta es más "teórica" que practica, el error del "Un Array vacio es igual a false" lo he visto ya muchas veces en casos que si son prácticos, por ejemplo:
const resp = await fecth(url);
const array = await resp.json();
if(array){
  console.log("No hay datos") //Siempre entrá acá
}


Edito para explicar un punto:

[] es verdadero (Truthy en rigor)
[] == false también es verdadero

Son 2 expresiones distintas y no equivalentes.
La pregunta utiliza la primera expresión, y la respuesta emplea la segunda, entonces la respuesta está contestando cualquier cosa, menos lo que se pregunta y solo por eso, la respuesta ya es incorrecta.
Aun que el problema principal, y lo que me llevo a hacer este post, es la aseveración de que "Un Array vacío es igual a false", el cual da información incorrecta a los que vienen buscando información.

En cualquier caso, gracias al efecto Meta y a varios usuarios, la pregunta ha bajado de posición (Una pequeña victoria para la humanidad)

No soy experto en js, y por lo tanto no podria validar lo que decis.. pero el snipet al ejecutarlo da todo true. De igual forma, no, no se puede borrar una respuesta por mas que sea erronea, para eso estan los votos. Bajo que concepto un moderador podria borrar algo porque "parece" erroneo?

Creo que la respuesta es incorrecta, podrías dejar un comentario a ver si el autor se decide a darle un retoque, aunque con +60 (+66-6) quizás siga pensando que es correcta. La otra es votar por la respuesta que creas que cubre la pregunta, a ver si logra superar en votos a la aceptada (cosa que es deseable en estos casos)

@gbianchi Esto me recuerda a esta discusión https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/620916/301324. En JS ![] es falso y [] == false es verdadero, son 2 cosas distintas. Entiendo la peligrosidad de lo que planteas, a mí no me gusta la idea que moderadores borren respuestas y menos porque "parecen" erróneas. Se me ocurre que estos casos excepcionales se puedan debatir aquí en META y tomar una decisión (no sé si eso será posible).

Por otro lado, he visto muchas veces que se borran o pasan a comentarios respuestas que son correctas, pero son de baja calidad. Generalmente cuando no están acompañadas de una explicación. Y una respuesta incorrecta no es también una respuesta de baja calidad?? Incluso peor que no tener explicación

No. una respuesta de baja calidad es una respuesta a la cual le falta todo. Esta es una respuesta completa, puede o no ser erronea, pero si en su momento no se detecto el problema, no se puede ahcer nada desde el lado de la moderacion diamantada. Es mas, aunque voten en masa aca (que tampoco valdria, me falta alguien?) sigue sin poder borrarse...

@Yussef también podrías editar la respuesta y arreglar tu mismo el error, de esta forma harías un bien mayor a la comunidad

@Japv Es que no puedo ser yo quien decida unilateralmente si una respuesta es correcta o incorrecta, ni pasar por sobre 60 personas que dieron su voto positivo, mi opinión no vale más que la de ellos. Pero ciertamente hay un problema, supongo que la idea es a medida que vayamos encontrando errores los corrijamos, pero que pasa cuando un usuario ya no entra más al sitio??? no basta con dejar un mensaje que nunca verá

@Yussef la respuesta como tal no es "incorrecta", pero si tiene un error de concepto en la primera oración, ya que un arreglo vacío es true y no falso como dice quien responde, si solo se quitará esa parte todo estaría perfecto

@Japv Si quitas esa parte lo que sigue no tiene sentido, el OP construye toda la respuesta en base a esa premisa

Si ejecuto let a = []; if( a ) console.log( "true" );, imprime true, lo que parece darle la razón a Yussef, pero console.log( [] == false ); imprime true.... mi no entender!, es un error de javascript?.

la herramienta de desarrollo de google chrome en su ultima version indica que la respuesta es correcta: https://i.imgur.com/GzzWD79.png tienes evidencia de que no sea asi????????????????

si usamos variable definidas para la comprobacion ... sigue dando true: https://i.imgur.com/y8wIa7B.png

tambien hice mi aporte a esa pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/622235/315134

la respuesta es correcta pero no explica la coercion y como esta interactua en javascript probocando confusion en la implementacion de la coercion de tipos.

@MarcePuente Para mí es un error de javascript, porque atenta contra la lógica booleana que es un principio básico. La explicación es que cuando tienes la operación [] == false hay 2 tipos diferentes, en este caso JS intenta pasar ambos tipos a números: false es cero. Pero en el caso de un array, se convierte a string, el cual imprime los valores del array separados por coma, pero en este caso como es vacío, imprime un string vacío "", luego el string vacío a número Number("") es cero, entonces 0==0

Entonces [] es verdadero y el resultado de la operación [] == false es verdadero también, que son contradictorios, sin duda, pero es así. El punto central es lo que aparece en la pregunta ¿En la pregunta aparece [] o aparece [] == false?. Es por eso que afirmo que la respuesta es incorrecta

Y lo que me lleva a hacer este post, es que en este caso no es solo incorrecta, si no que lleva a errores peligrosos (aquí en los comentarios queda en evidencia). Ya que he visto, no pocas veces, cometer el error que expongo al final de mi publicación

Gracias Maestro, terminé de entenderlo con la explicación de Francisco Nuñez IA Lover, y solo puedo decir una cosa, es una característica horrible!!.

@Yussef no es contradictorio es la jerarquia de conversion de tipos, mal implementada por los usuarios ... la practica de convinar coersion y manipulacion de datos es en general una mala practica ... por eso es mejor utilizar tipado y POO ... no estas chapusas ...

No conbinen Coersion con Operadores Unarios

Que tu puedas hacer un Proceso de la A - Z por que asi esta diseñado un sistema... y que por alguna razon cuando llegas a la M te das cuenta que el sistema de Permite desviarte a un sub proceso no relacionado M-E1 no quiere decir que debas hacerlo o que sea buena practica... lo mismo esta pasando aqui... se estan mesclando 2 caracteristicas que no fueron diseñadas y varias comparaciones que no fueron diseñadas para funcionar de esa forma ... a pesar de que el lenguaje lo permita...

por el ejemplo, SOes tiene un formulario para hacer preguntas ... eso no quiere decir que todas las preguntas hechas sean correctas ...

Punto menos para javascript. Solo los boleanos deberían tener coerción a enteros. No veo caso alguno en que sea util convertir una lista a número usando operadores unarios. Esto y el "undefined" me hace pensar que los del Ecma no programaron nada en sus vidas.

@DanteS. Yo soy un convencido que esto son errores, es que es imposible llamarlo de otra manera, y que no los solucionaron (ni van a hacerlo) por mantener la retrocompatibilidad. Creo que deberían crear otro lenguaje paralelo a javascript e ir matando a este último lentamente

La respuesta no está incorrecta, es confusa para quienes no manejan el tema de coerción de tipos... y como interactúa en javascript.
Aunque la respuesta sea correcta, la implementación de Coerción de tipo se presta para confusiones cuando no se explica y se detalla por que ocurren ciertas cosas raras, como otras muchas cosas que ocurren en javascript. Y que no ocurren en otros lenguajes…
Incluso puede pensarse que es un bug y tampoco lo es…
Para aclarar un poco más he dado mi respuesta, con un poco más de detalles y ejemplos prácticos tratando de que aun sea una respuesta simple:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/622235/315134

No se si esto pueda ser viable:

Creo que puede pasar es que un mod fusione dos respuestas con la segunda mejor respuesta y que tenga la explicación de la coerción, y que este coloque que la respuesta explicada seria la recomendada.



Por otro lado en el sitio en ingles equipos de trabajo de lenguajes y estos equipos de trabajo recomiendan las respuestas correctas. No sé si esto lo pueda solucionar en un futuro.



por otro lado:
Sigo pensando que las personas que están respondiendo/editando/moderando, aunque la pregunta sea mala, las respuestas deberían de ceñirse un poco más al contexto ... de lo contrario todas las preguntas al final serian duplicadas de otra o tendría una pobre redacción/explicación como es el caso de esta...
